# How to infer return type of function returned from a function in c++

Tags: c++, templates, auto

Consider this code

```
template <typename OUT>
auto fun(const int& x) {
  return [&](function<OUT(int)> fout) -> decltype(fout(x)) {return fout(x);};
}
```

calling function

```
auto w = fun(23)([](const auto& x) {return x*2;});
```

The function fun when called cannot deduce the return type as above code fails compilation with an error saying that "candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'OUT'". However when explicitly provided output type this works.

1. Please help me with the appropriate decltype declaration for my returning function inside fun function so that the callee can automatically deduce the return type.
2. Also help me with reference materials that I can refer to debug the compiler auto deduction.

Comment: If you break things down into its individual steps... how is the compiler supposed to deduce `OUT` from only seeing `fun(23)`? You can return a generic lambda, so the deduction of the return type comes in the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this code:

```
template <typename OUT>
auto fun(const int& x) {
  return [&](function<OUT(int)> fout) -> decltype(fout(x)) {return fout(x);};
}
```

it is **impossible** to deduce `OUT` because it is **impossible** to know what `OUT` *could* be when calling `fun(0)`. Your lambda needs to be the template, not the outer function.

```
auto fun(const int& x) {
  return [x](auto&& fout) { return std::forward<decltype(fout)>(fout)(x); };
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7ETWjq7hK)

Comment: great this one does works, can you suggest me any reference material to understand template deduction better. Also some guidance on how to debug them.

Comment: There are a few great Cpp-Con talks by Walter E. Brown and Scott Meyers on Youtube about this topic.

Comment: Thanks @tkausl i will check out :)